# javascript/jquery simulate anchor "tel" click

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have found lots of messages about simulating an anchor click with javascript. Most using the  "location" function, which doesn't work for me because I do not want to redirect anywhere. My anchor has href="tel:..." to invoke the iphone's phone function.

I can't have an anchor for clicking, so I wanted to have javascript/jquery simulate that click when a user presses a button, for example. How could I do this (if, indeed, it is even possible)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the click event for the anchor on on the click of the button

```
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    $('#anchor1').click();  // triggering the click event on click of the button
});
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/HbqVp/1/)

```
$(function() {

    $('a').on('click' , function() {

       alert('Fired using button !!')
    });

    $('#button1').on('click' , function() {

       $('a').click();

        alert('Button Clicked !!')
    });

});​
```

Comment: While it works in FIDDLE, it doesn't actually do what I need it to. Your button clicks the anchor, which triggers a function. I need the button to click the anchor, and have the anchor then perform it's native function, i.e. call someone. If, in your FIDDLE, you replace the href="#" with href="http://www.google.com" you would see that it doesn't work as I need it to. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(your_button).trigger('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just trigger the click event...

```
$("a.phonenumber").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to accomplish this -

```
$(function(){
    $("#b1").on('click',function(){
      alert("pressed b1!");
    });        
    
     $("#b2").on('click',function(){
      $("#b1").trigger('click');
      alert("pressed b2!");
    });        
});​
```

Clicking on the first `b1` button will trigger an alert. When clicking the second `b2` button, first we "trigger" a click event on the first button (which will execute it's alert), and then alert the second value.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wMT2r/)

Comment: Refer to comment above, as it is the same for this one.

Comment: To cancel the default action of an anchor tag that has an href parameter, all you have to do is add a `return false` to it's click handler.

Answer (score 0):

I know the questions asks not to use the location function, but please try this out:

HTML:

```
<button class="click-to-call" data-phone="2125551234">call</button>
```

jQuery:
(could easily be written with only javascript too if you wanted to)

```
$('.click-to-call').on('click',function(){
    window.location.assign('tel:'+ $(this).data('phone'));
});
```